# Windows Small Business Server 2008 Standard & Sharepoint Services 3.0

Tags: windows-server-2008, sharepoint, wss-3.0

My current configuration is a Windows Small Business Server 2003 running Windows Sharepoint Services 2.0 with MSSQL 2000.

My question pertains to the feasability of running Windows Sharepoint Services 3.0 on Windows Small Business Server 2008 Standard (not Premium).

Because Windows Small Business Server 2008 Standard Edition will run on one hardware server, running a 'Basic' installation will create a Windows Internal Database on the server. Would an 'Advanced' installation allow me to specify a configuration database, specifically on another 2003 server containing MSSQL 2000? Can this scenario work with SBS 2008 Standard?

My goal is to migrate the existing database to Sharepoint 3.0 and use my new server containing Windows SBS 2008 Standard as the 'application' server.

I'm also fully aware that I can perform side-by-side installation of WSS 3.0 and WSS 2.0 without breaking the integration between my Windows Small Business Server 2003 and Windows SharePoint Services 2.0.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Be wary of basic installations. See http://www.sharepointjoel.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=0cd1a63d-183c-4fc2-8320-ba5369008acb&ID=260

Answer (score 1):

SBS2008 locks you into a special version of SQL2005 that runs the WSUS database, Sharepoint, and the SBS specific database (keeps track of users, alerts, etc). It works just fine. With SBS 2008 premium you get the extra 2k8 license with a license of SQL (i think you can choose 2008 or 2005) to run your line of business app (if any) and these other databases. if you have a big enough machine, there is no reason to get premium- you'll run into 75 user limit on standard before you run into any database performance problems. you can always move the databases to dedicated disks if you want, on standard.

i don't think sharepoint 3 is compatible with SQL 2000.

Answer (score -1):

IF you want to move WSS3.0 on SBS2008, it will work. I don't understand correctly the relation with MySQL (Maybe because I'm french and my english is not that good...) so I just want to confirm to you that you can install WSS2.0 and upgrade it to 3.0.

Well, I can't tell you at 100% that it will work with MySQL but give it a try. However, WSS3.0 will work on SBS 2008 STD and Business Edition.

If you have clarifications, let me know. I will give you a hand!

Regards,
David.

Comment: @r0ca: Think you misread... @jarek was talking about MSSQL not MySQL